# Can I join a Minecraft Pocket Edition world on my PC through LAN?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is the exact opposite question of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft-on-lan). My kids both have Android tablets and are playing Minecraft PE. They want me to join them on their PE world from my Windows PC over our LAN. Is this possible? If not with the PC version of Minecraft, is there a way to emulate the Android version on the PC?

Comment: How is it the opposite? They are still different games, no matter how you look at it, no?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase or add that I have heard of some people using emulation to run the Android version on their PCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are two different games. You can, however, emulate Android on your computer. See [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/) or [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) but please note that most Android emulators run very slowly and will likely not run Minecraft PE at an enjoyable level.

For a quick recap of the tutorials:

1. [Download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) the Android SDK and extract it
2. Run SDK Setup.exe and follow the steps
3. After installation, select Virtual Devices from the left menu, and then click the new button
4. Fill in the required fields and click Create AVD
5. Select your newly created virtual device and click start
6. You are now running a virtual edition of android. You can connect it to your google play account and download Minecraft PE

Comment: I should add that most android emulators are pretty slow

Comment: Playing Minecraft in an Android emulator on your computer must be the least pleasant way to play Minecraft.