# Unable to connect locally to minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I want to turn an old ubuntu laptop into a minecraft server supposed to run within my home.
Minecraft is in place, I can fire it up and see the gui and run it in a terminal as well.

Laptop IP is 192.168.0.22 and according to server.properties the port is 25565 but when I enter these information into minecraft pe on my phone I am unable to connect to the server.

My goal is just to let this run within our home no public access is needed. But what am I missing?

Comment: I don't believe a regular minecraft server can be used for minecraft PE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't connect to a regular Minecraft server through Minecraft: Pocket Edition.

Here is a guide on how to setup a Pocket Edition server: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2014/06/how-to-create-a-minecraft-pe-server/

Comment: Is there any official source you could mention? I trust you, but it would be great if you would link to one

Answer (score -2):

For a home LAN PE server, simply:
- Use an old iPod Touch (Gen3 or newer), 
- Install the app (free since I already bought it), 
- Set lock screen time to "never" (Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never),
- Start the app
- Set volume to zero
- Place on shelf on charger
- Forget

This gives you a free, full feature, no maintenance MinecraftPE server.
  You can copy an existing world from your current device with free programs like iExplorer.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  You're just bypassing their issue with, "Hey, forget your method, just use this instead."