# Can I Invite PE Players To My PC Realms Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to invite my son (IOS Pocket Edition) to my realms server (mac osx).

1. I keep getting the response `"Could Not Invite The Provided Name"` when I try to invite him. His name is all regular characters with no spaces . . . just letters and numbers.  **Are the two game types incompatible, and if they are**
2. Is it possible to create the same type of 24/7 available server that is only open to him and other invitees like the OSX realms?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: There's no cross-compatibility between PE and PC. You can't do it.

Comment: minecraft.gamepedia.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that there is more code in the PC version, and more, and diverse, blocks in PC, It is safe to say that PC and PE are pretty much different games entirely. If your son gets the PC version, *then* he could join, but his username is not registered in the Mojang servers. If you want, you could put PE on another device, and play together like that, but you cannot put PE together with PC.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have different versions(PC & and Pocket Edition) you won't be able to play together. The only OS that is compatible between mobile and Desktop is Windows 10. You can get yourself a PE Version or get him PC version. I encourage the second one because it'd be more complete