# Minecraft Server 1.8.9 - Can't Connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have two newly set up Minecraft 1.8.9 servers.  With both servers when I point my Pocket Edition clients to them I receive an "Unable to connect to world." message.

```
1) Debian 8
2) CentOS 7

[root@minecraft Downloads]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Both servers behaving the same way, I did a packet capture on each and can see *UDP* traffic reaches each them.  And both servers respond with ICMP Port Unreachable.  No surprise since the *UDP* port is not open I found.  Minecraft server is only opening the *TCP* port...

```
[root@minecraft Downloads]# netstat -anp |grep 25565
tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:25565           :::*                    LISTEN      21202/java
```

I looked through Minecraft's `server.properties` documentation and see nothing pertaining to the protocol being configurable, only the port.

Comment: Based on the lack of response I'm guessing this forum is about game-play and not technical issues??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Comment: @pppery Why did you add [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition]? 1.8.9 is not a bedrock version. Nor do I think that's the correct dupe target.

Comment: @Schism Look at the answer; I added [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition] because the answer turned out to be "the user is trying to connect to a Java Edition server from Bedrock Edition clients", which is also the exact question asked in the duplicate.

Comment: @pppery Thanks for clarifying -- I saw this in the close vote queue, which doesn't show answers. Adding the tag is fine but I think editing the question text would make it more clear why you made such an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game clients are all Pocket Edition.  I'm told that PE clients cannot connect to "PC" ("standard") edition servers.