# I cannot invite friends to my Minecraft realm that are using an iPad

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have purchased Minecraft Java Edition for my Dell PC.  I also purchased a monthly renewable subscription to Minecraft Realms for up to 10 players. Lastly, I setup a Microsoft XBox Live account which I understood is necessary to invite other players using other platforms/devices. My grandson has Minecraft on his iPAD.

We have a Microsoft family account and my grandson, daughter, and me are all on it. My grandson is only seven, but we set his security to allow him to communicate with friends, and accept gaming requests from friends. When we are both logged into XBox Live, we can now see each other as friends/followers.

When I go into my Realm and try to send an invite to my grandson, I get a message that says it cannot send an invite to the person that I typed in.  I am typing in his gametag. What am I doing incorrectly? Why can't I invite him into my realm so that we can play Minecraft together. It is supposed to be our grandpa/grandson bonding activity.

Comment: I am not sure but does Minecraft has cross platform play on all those platforms? Pretty sure XBL/PC has it, but for iPads I'm not convinced.

Comment: It is supposed to work. https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/20/16339242/minecraft-cross-platform-update-better-together-windows-10-pc-mobile-switch-xbox Is the iPad version up to date?

Comment: I don't know if the iPad version is up to date.  I am currently at work, but I will check when I get home and answer your question definitely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft on LAN?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft-on-lan)

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft Java edition and Minecraft Pocked edition are completely separate games. They are made to look similar, but they're actually not. You cannot play on the same server with both.

Comment: So even using a Realm, they cannot play together?  I know that this sounds dumb, but I am completly new to Mindcraft.

Comment: Pocket edition seems to not exist anymore. https://www.apple.com/ca/search/minecraft?src=serp So if he uses the old free pocket edition I guess it's normal it doesnt work.

Comment: @DonHarris Yes. Also, "Min->e<-craft". ;)

Comment: @Fredy31 What kind of website is that? Minecraft's website is minecraft.com. And Pocket edition is Windows 10 edition or Bedrock edition or "better together update" edition or whatever. There are many names for it and I prefer to use the one that shows what it really is: A game with a lot of limitations that are imposed on it due to the fact that it has to run on mobile phones.

Comment: @FabianRöling Minecraft's website is actually minecraft.net

Comment: @pppery Oh, right. Thanks for the correction. I can't edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 versions of minecraft:
1)Java edition(25 bucks~)
2)Bedrock edition
The first one can run on any PC with java installed(OS doesn't quite matter), the second one is cross-platform(ps4-xbox-win10-phone-ipad... no java).
These two versions are "similar" but have some diferences on game mechanics and other things. 
An other thing to note is that realms can be of these 2 versions, too.

**If you have one version you won't be able to connect to a realm/server for the other version. The only thing you can do is to buy an other version of the bedrock edition for win 10(in case you have windows 8 or 10 as OS) and ask for a refund of the java edition version**