# Can you connect to a game on Java edition from MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've played Minecraft with my younger sister for a while now, but it has all been on MCPE. Now I am going to download it on my mac, but i don't know if she will still be able to join my world from her phone once I am playing on java edition. Will she?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no cross-platform compatability for Minecraft Java Edition.

Comment: This is misleading. The Bedrock version of minecraft is cross-compatable with Xbox, PC, and iOS. The Java edition is not cross platform at all.

Comment: That's what I said. Java Edition has no cross compatability.

Answer (score 0):

You could play on Java edition with a server like Hypixel for example and your sister could get the Hypixel server on her Minecraft PE and you could play together in a server.