# Can MCPE and MC Java Edition play together

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been seeing different articles. Granted some are years old. Is it possible when you are in the same internet connection to play together with mcpe and mc Java Edition and how? I was thinking mainly of using LAN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. Mainly because each edition of Minecraft is different. Minecraft Pocket Edition, which is also called mcpe, is played on the Android, iOS, Windows 10, Windows Phone, Windows 10 Mobile, and Fire OS. Because of all the phones and maybe tablets, I don't know which ones are tablets, Pocket Edition is controlled differently. I've watched videos of people playing pocket edition, and their characters where a little... robotic? I play Java Edition and the player is more smooth in movement, so I don't think it's possible to join the 2 editions.

Comment: I'll see myself