# Getting java edition, and play with a person on Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister plays Minecraft: Bedrock Edition on a phone, I want to get Java edition but my sister is on Bedrock. Can we still play with each other? Or can I only play with people on Java Edition?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please understand that our site allows experienced users to edit other users' questions and answers to make them clearer. For example, we've edited your reference to "regular Minecraft" to refer to Bedrock Edition, which is the official name we think you're playing on. I would also like to quickly mention that there is no "regular" edition of Minecraft, in fact, if any, it would be Java Edition, because it was developed first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

Java Edition and Bedrock Edition do not have native crossplay. However, you can use a proxy like [Geyser](https://geysermc.org/) to connect to a Java server from a Bedrock Edition client (your sister's phone). You will need to run a standalone JE server.

Download the server software from [Mojang's official page](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server), put it in its own folder, and run the downloaded .jar file. You can copy the folder of your existing world and paste it into the server folder, but you have to rename it to "world".

After setting up the server, you must set up Geyser.
[This section of the Geyser wiki](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/wiki/Setup) explains how to set it up.

You can connect with the server IP "localhost", and your sister can connect with your LAN IP on the port 19132.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, joining a Bedrock World or server whilst on Java Edition is impossible whilst in the base game.

However there are some external programs you can run to connect to each other but I imagine some in game things may not work properly.