# Are Android and iOS Minecraft editions on their app stores capable of connecting to Java Edition servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Minecraft game apps on iOS and Android are both now simply labeled as "Minecraft."  Can these connect to standard Minecraft and PaperMC servers or is some other plugin/module to modify something like PaperMC to work with these mobile editions of Minecraft?

I'm thinking that they've dropped the "Bedrock" and "PE" nomenclature, but it still may exist and is simply confusing in this respect...

Comment: they dropped the name but its still bedrock edition, and still separate from java when not using specialized tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super short answer: No - BUT it is possible via a "bridge" tool like Geyser.

It appears that my original assumption is the case in that mobile versions are still "PE" and require "Bedrock" servers and something like [Geyser](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/) is needed to allow mobile editions (no longer called, this but they still are essentially the same things, just named differently) to function with something like [Paper](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper) or [Purpur](https://purpur.pl3x.net/).

Comment: Keep in mind there is no longer such a thing as just the mobile editions