# How can I link Minecraft Java to an iPhone 12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I have Minecraft Java Edition on my windows computer. Is there any way to link those worlds to my iPhone 12? I want to be able to access the worlds from my phone, as well as my computer.

Comment: The one you are playing on iPhone should be Bedrock version, and I don't think it's compatible with Java edition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Minecraft Pocket Edition play with a desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90308/can-minecraft-pocket-edition-play-with-a-desktop-minecraft)

Comment: @pinckerman yeah, it's definitely not compatible in any way. The programming languages used to write them are also different.

Answer (score 2):

### **Short Answer:**

You can't.
Minecraft Bedrock and Minecraft Java are two different versions. You can't directly link them together to edit the same file at the same time. However, there is another way.

### **Another way:**

You can convert the file to bedrock and add it to your phone. There is a tool called Je2be and there are a few tutorials on it.
One tutorial:

After converting the file, you can transfer the file to your phone.